# Unable to view Applications Directory Content in Terminal

Tags: osx, directory-structure

Not sure what I'm missing here, but when I try to list the contents of the Applications directory from the Terminal it produces a directory with a couple .dmg files and none of the actual application directories or content.

I would like to get access to the list of actual Applications within the directory. I'm on Yosemite and have attached a screen shot. Any help would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `~/Applications/` Folder and Not `/Applications`.

Try:

```
cd /Applications
```

And then:

```
ls
```

`~` Means home, which is `/Users/user/`. There is a users Application folder but it is very rarely used and it is for Applications that are installed for only that certain user. All default Applications are in `/Applications`.

Comment: Wow, really humbled here. I tried all manner of combinations other than the most simple one. Just not paying attention. Thanks for the your quick response to this simple question.